# Node.js Mongodb - Kerberos module not found

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, kerberos

Im trying to npm install mongodb.
It works and tells me that modules are installed, kerberos is in this list.

But when im trying to run my app i keep getting this:

```
Error: Cannot find module '../build/Release/kerberos' from '/Users/snorre edwin/Code/raspberry-node-         server/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/node_modules/kerberos/lib'
Error: Cannot find module '../../../build/Release/kerberos' from '/Users/snorre edwin/Code/raspberry-node-server/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/node_modules/kerberos/lib/win32/wrappers'
Error: Cannot find module '../../../build/Release/kerberos' from '/Users/snorre edwin/Code/raspberry-node-server/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/node_modules/kerberos/lib/win32/wrappers'
Error: Cannot find module '../../../build/Release/kerberos' from '/Users/snorre edwin/Code/raspberry-node-server/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/node_modules/kerberos/lib/win32/wrappers'
Error: Cannot find module '../../../build/Release/kerberos' from '/Users/snorre edwin/Code/raspberry-node-server/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/node_modules/kerberos/lib/win32/wrappers'
```

It doesnt make sense, since this is a module which comes with the mongodb package.

Anyone else experienced this?

Answer (score 0):

A quick Google found this discussion thread: https://nodejstools.codeplex.com/workitem/532. Although it is in context of Microsoft VS.

### Different, possible solutions include:

1. Instal mongoose (not mongo) globally using `npm install mongoose -g`.

   > So I fixed this issue by installing mongoose globally via NPM, then I copied the build folder in the mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/kerberos to my local mongoose folder in my VS project.
2. If you're using mongoose, the thread additionally suggests you'll need python installed.
3. Add kerberos to the package.json file itself. Also try to install globally.
4. Ignore it:

[image]

Comment: Iv been through that google search. I dont really want mongoose, it gives me way to much than what I need. Python should not be a dependability, thats just strange. I could try to install it globally, but its not looking for it globally, its looking internally in its own pacakges, where it acctually exists.